# Publishing to MDPI and reupload at researchgate?

Tags: legal-issues

Is it legal to publish an Open Access article at MDPI and then reupload this article after publication at researchgate? Furthermore, is it possible to change the layout of the article into a standard 2-column article for the upload at researchgate? I am asking because I do not know if there are any legal issues with this.

I am not very happy with the layout of articles at mdpi, but I didnt came across a different publisher, that is that fast, which is the reason I choose mdpi.

Comment: The first and foremost question is, why do you want to do it? Being Open Access means accessible to all. Why do you want to put it up on ResearchGate? What's the point?

Comment: I simply do not like the layout at mdpi, which is hard to read.

Comment: Well, that's a personal preference then! You must have a preprint/early draft of the paper. You can put that on ResearchGate/ should already have right after you finished the initial draft!

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/is-mdpi-a-reputable-academic-publisher

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/149929/is-researchgate-still-useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have the right to do this under the [Creative Commons CC BY 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) that [MDPI uses as standard](https://www.mdpi.com/openaccess), as long as you link back to the original version and give credit to authors and publisher. [You retain copyright as an author](https://www.mdpi.com/authors/rights).